# Pytorch not finding more than 1 GPU from SLURM job

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, slurm

I'm using SLURM to assign some GPU nodes from a supercomputer for an ML job I have.

Everything works fine for a single GPU (1 node), but when set the SLURM script for more than 1 job, the python script still seems to only detect 1 GPU. First of all, I'm certain that the nodes are being reserved because of the output right below:

[image]

Now, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but this is my SLURM file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --time=00:03:00
#SBATCH -N 4
#SBATCH -C TitanX
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH -o myfile.out

# Load GPU drivers
module load cuda11.1/toolkit
module load cuDNN/cuda11.1

# This loads the anaconda virtual environment with our packages
source /home/user/.bashrc
conda activate env_37

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3

# Run the actual experiment
python train.py --name gm --workers 4 --shuffle --keep_step 1000 --decay_step 1000
```

And my Python script for calling the GPUs:

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = "0,1,2,3"
model.cuda()
model.train()
    
# adding for multiple GPUs    
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
    model = nn.DataParallel(model, gpu_ids = [0,1,2,3])
    
# is cuda being used?
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
print(torch.cuda.current_device())
print(torch.cuda.device(0))
print(torch.cuda.device_count())
print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))
```

The output of `device_count()` gives me 1. I'm still not sure if the problem lies with my python script or with the SLURM script. The highest available CUDA toolkit version on the supercomputer is 11.1 (as far as I know) and I loaded this module in the SLURM script, however the conda environment running the python script uses a higher CUDA version. But since the code already worked with 1 GPU, I doubt that this is the problem. I hope someone can help!

Comment: what you have here is not enough for multinode training.  Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/TengdaHan/1dd10d335c7ca6f13810fff41e809904) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating 1 GPU to your sbatch job with `#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1`

If you have 4 GPUs to use, you should change this option to `#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4`

See the documentation on `gres` for more info: https://slurm.schedmd.com/gres.html

Comment: This is not the problem. I did not realise that my setup did not match with this scenario. I need to use the DistributedDataParallel module since I'm working with different nodes. I am going to post a different question about that and close this one.